# WP10 TP Unable to get License Information 0xC03F7000

Tags: vb.net, in-app-purchase, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm testing my In-app purchases on my WP8.1 app as-is on Win 10 Tech Preview (tried on device as well as emulator with same result) and facing the following error while trying to get License Information.

**Exception:**

> System.Exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0xC03F7000 at
>   Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.get_LicenseInformation() at
>   App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)

**Code:**

```
Dim oLicense As LicenseInformation
oLicense = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation
```

This is working fine on WP8.1. When I tried ***CurrentAppSimulator***.LicenseInformation, I get a different error.

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: The system cannot find the path
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003) at
>   Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator.get_LicenseInformation()

Any help/pointer is appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the same error in c#. Works on 8.1, not on 10.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been resolved with the release of Windows 10. It was a platform issue while in Technical preview stage.